# Delete text between two strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm triying to delete the text between `include` and the next `&` in the text:

```
filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor&sort=scheduled
```

and get a text like:

```
filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&sort=scheduled
```

I tried with the following codes:

```
function delete_all_between($string)
{
    $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
    $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
    if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false)
        return $string;
}
```

and also with:

```
preg_replace("/\include[^]+\&/","",$string);
```

But none worked.

It may also be that the text also has the following format:

```
filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&sort=scheduled&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor
```

With which I need to delete from the word include to the end (in this case there is no `&`)

EDIT:
This question isn't duplicated because that answer didn't work for me!

Comment: Why not split it on `&` characters with explode? This also looks like a URL parameter string, so you can use `parse_str()` to turn it into an associative array.

Comment: Why do you escape the `i` character in the regexp? `\i` means the TAB character.

Comment: What's the purpose of `[^)]+`? There are no `)` characters in your string, why do you have to exclude them?

Comment: It's usually best to put a regexp in single quotes, so that escape sequences aren't processed by PHP, only the regexp engine.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3zUwJF/1, something like this should help you

Comment: [^)]+ was a mistake, I edited. That works for the case: `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor&sort=scheduled` but not when the include is in the last part of url

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this :

```
preg_replace('/(include(.*)\&)|(\&include([^&]*)$)/i', '', $string)
```

I tested with :

- `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor&sort=scheduled`

**Result :** `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&sort=scheduled`

- `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor`

**Result :** `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available`

- `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&INCLUDE=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor&sort=scheduled`

**Result :** `filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&sort=scheduled`

Comment: Why do you escape `\i`? That should probably be `\bi` so it matches a word boundary before `include`.

Comment: This won't work if the parameter is at the end of the string, like the second example.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Barmar, i will edit my answer

Comment: This is a misguided answer that doesn't work in all situations.  For example, what happens if the string is just `include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor`?

Answer (score 2):

The string you are dealing with is in a particular format that can be parsed by [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and reassembled via [http_build_query](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.http-build-query.php).

```
<?php

$str = "filter[mat]=1&filter[status]=available&include=homeCompetitor,awayCompetitor&sort=scheduled";
parse_str($str, $output);
unset($output["include"]);
echo http_build_query($output);
```